# How do I make the Reputation Graph go back further?

Tags: support

Here is the reputation graph on the activity page of one of our moderators which goes all the way back to September, 9 months

[image]

Here is my reputation graph which only goes back to March, 5 months

[image]

Despite my best efforts I cannot figure out why My chart only goes back 5 months not 9, Is this a bug or is there some other reason I don't know of?

Comment: Using https://stackexchange.com/users/6643204/tres-2b?tab=reputation, I see your reputation since July 17th 2015. Which I believe is when you got your first reputation on WB...

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out too; in addition to seeing different behavior for different users on a site, I saw different behavior for my accounts on different sites.  What gives?

The size of the slices shown in the graph depends on how long you've had the account:

- If the account is 4 years old, the graph is shown in years.  (That's not possible on this site yet.)
- If the account is 1 year old, the graph is shown in quarters (as in your first example).
- If the account is 4 months old (I think; can't find an example to verify the lower bound), the graph is shown in months.
- Otherwise, the graph is shown in 10-day intervals.

Your account isn't yet a year old, so you're still seeing the months view.  This should change for you in a few weeks.

You can see all of your reputation by going to the reputation tab on your site or network profile.  The small graph on your profile is meant as more of a snapshot, not a complete history.